# Impossible to connect to LocalHost Xampp 127.0.0.1

Tags: xampp, pgadmin

[image: PgAdmin]

[image: Mysql Pgadmin]

Am unable to connect to xampp with pgAdmin what could be the problem ?

Answer (score 0):

do you need check the port in the firewell, i think this  port  5432, this locked